# understanding with AD requests

Tags: powershell, active-directory

So, I want to do something with AD.

Get every attribute, of every elements in a specific folder of my AD.
Here is my current code, I also don't really understand it.

```
$strDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $strDomain
$objSearcher.PageSize = 100
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "subtree"

 

# Specify attribute values to retrieve.
$arrAttributes = @("distinguishedName","sn","givenname")
ForEach($strAttribute In $arrAttributes)
{
    $objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($strAttribute) > $Null
}


# Filter on object with specified Common Name.
$objSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(CN=*))"

 

$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()
ForEach ($strResult In $colResults)
{
    $strDN = $strResult.Properties.Item("distinguishedName") + "," + $strResult.Properties.Item("givenname")
    Write-Host $strDN
}
```

The issue with this is that the filters don`t work like I think they do and putting anything other that CN=* gives nothing in return.
And the second issue is that it gives me everything in the AD. even non-users

I noticed a path and was wondering if I could use that to get to the folder and then use the "foreach"
but the path looks like this :

```
CN="user",OU="folder I want",OU="parent folder",DC,DC,DC
```

PS: For security reasons I can`t give the actual path since I don't know what it is "worth" and would rather not take chances.

But my issue with it are 2 things:

1. there's multiple "OU" and "DC"
2. its in reverse to the usual paths (like with the file explorer)

so with this is there a way to target my OU="folder I want" and extract its users?
And can you explain how it works in the process as well plz?

Thanks.

Comment: You say you want to _Get every attribute, of every elements in a specific folder_, but the code specifically filters on users. In PowerShell, have a look at [Get-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser). There's examles there too..

Comment: in the folder that interests me, there should only be users, but for now, the filters don't work.

I get everything in the AD with this code.
I'm currently looking at Get-ADUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get properties for all users inside a specific OU (folder as you call it), all you have to do is

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# enter the DistinguishedName of the OU in which you want to search for users
$UsersOU = 'OU=FolderYouWant,OU=Users,DC=YourDomain,DC=com'

# Get-ADUser returns by default these properties
# DistinguishedName, Enabled, GivenName, Name, ObjectClass, ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname, UserPrincipalName
# so in this case that is more than enough. If you want extra properties
# just ask for them using parameter `-Properties`
$result = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchRoot $UsersOU 

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# you can limit what you want to see, for instance
$result | Format-Table -Property DistinguishedName, GivenName, Surname

# or write this to a CSV file you can open in Excel
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\ADusers.csv' -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation
```

For the DistinguishedName of the OU to search in, open ADUC, right-click the OU select Properties and scroll down untill you see property `DistinguishedName`. Double-click that and copy.

P.S. A DistinguishedName is always in reverse as it is not a path format you are accustomed to with Windows folders. (the CanonicalName is more like that)

P.S.2 If you know the name of your OU to search in, but not the DistinguishedName, you can use this:

```
$UsersOU = (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "TheNameOfTheOUtheUsersAreIn"').DistinguishedName
```

Comment: Thanks, in the end my main issue was that I didn't have access to the active directory module.